# Retrieve LinkedIn User's Phone And Experience - LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

We currently building a web app to allow user to login via LinkedIn profile, may I know how can we retrieve the full profile information which included user phone number and organisation history? Currently we are just able to get name and profile picture with r_liteprofile permission, how do I get the r_fullprofile permission? Thanks.